# how to use macros with FreeMarker in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, template-engine, freemarker

hi i'm woriking in a spring mvc project and i want to use FreeMarker as my template engine, i 'm having problems using macros i want to create a master page or a layout with (the footer, header and menu)that i could use in my other pages, so far i'm doing a simple example in how to do it but i cant get it to work, the content that i put in the macro doesnt show my FreeMarker version is 2.3.21.

here is my freemarker java class configuration:

```
 @Bean
 public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
     FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer  =  new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
     freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
     freeMarkerConfigurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
     return freeMarkerConfigurer;
 }
 @Bean
 public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver() {
     FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
     viewResolver.setPrefix("");
     viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
     viewResolver.setCache(false);   //Set to true during production
     viewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
     return viewResolver;
 }
```

i'm saving my macro as a .html page like this myMacro.html

here is myMacro.html file

```
<#macro myMasterPage title="defaultTitle">
  <html>
  <body style="width:100%;height:100%">
      print me
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <#include "Header.html"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <#include "Menu.html"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <#nested/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <#include "Footer.html"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</#macro>
```

and this is  the page where i call the macro

myPage.html

```
[#import "/WEB-INF/views/myMacro.html" as layout /] [@layout.myMasterPage title="My test page"] ...content goes here... [/@layout.myMasterPage ]
```

my footer.html

```
<div><h1>this is the footer</h1></di
```

my header.html

```
<div><h1>this is the header</h1></div>
```

my menu.html

```
    <div>
  <h1>
     <ul>  
       <li>Menu item 1</li>  
       <li>Menu item 2</li>  
       <li>Menu item 3</li>  
       <li>Menu item 4</li>  
       <li>Menu item 5</li>  
       <li>Menu item 6</li>
     </ul>
  </h1>
</div>
```

and this is the output that i get when i access myPage.html

```
[#import "/WEB-INF/views/ApruebaFreeMarker.html" as layout /] [@layout.myMasterPage title="My test page"] ...content goes here... [/@layout.myMasterPage ]
```

this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String myPage(Model model) {
        logger.info("PAge with Macro inside");



        return "myPage";
    }
```

EDITED: i was using and alternative syntax  when i was importing my layout like this:

```
[#import "/WEB-INF/views/ApruebaFreeMarker.html" as layout /] [@layout.myMasterPage title="My test page"] ...content goes here... [/@layout.myMasterPage ]
```

but i edited like this and it works

```
<#import "myMacro.html" as layout>
<@layout.myLayout>
  <div><h1>Hello Dude</h1></div>
</@layout.myLayout>
```

but i have another question  i am new to freemarker and i dont know what is the difference if i save them as a .html or as a .ftl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using so called "Alternative (square bracket) syntax". Take a look here: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html
Most likely the problem would be solved by replacing square brackets on angle brackets, or (not sure about this) by using ([#ftl] as stated in the documentation) at the beginning of your templates.

Comment: yes it worked thanks i edited my question because i have another doubt

Comment: Regarding to your additional question: file extension is optional, it is just a way of "tagging" file for different tools (see wiki: filename extension). For example, if you open one of your freemaker template file with "html" extension in some IDE (let's say Intellij IDEA), you will  get a lot of error/warning messages. On the other hand, if you change the file extension to "ftl", there will be no error/warning messages (in case of valid freemaker syntax in your template). Plus you will get addit. features like auto complete, etc. So if I were you, I would consider using "ftl" extension.